# Setting default additional include/library paths in a Visual Studio C++ project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, configuration, include-path

Maybe I just did not really search for the right keywords yet, but I couldn't find a decent post about this.
The thing I want is that everytime I create a new c++ project, it should automatically add additional include and library paths into the project. Is there something like a default configuration manager or something similar? It really gets annoying to always add the same include paths and library paths into all the projects.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to define default project setting in a visual studio solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20658106/how-to-define-default-project-setting-in-a-visual-studio-solution)

Answer (score -1):

You can choose the empty project option when creating your project, so you don't include unnecessary library paths. I hope I can help you!